# In flutter ListView.builder I got Null value

Tags: android, flutter, listview, dart

I created a map called "records", the keys of this map are taken from the user when presed on 'save' botton, and the values are from the time counter that I have in my code.
But the problem is when I create a ListView.builder to export this map indexes to cards, it gave me Null values in each card index !!!
How can I show the real value instead of Null ?!!

Here is my code:

```
var _item;
  List listCount = [];

  Map<String, dynamic> records = {};
  String name;

  createAlertDialog(buildContext, context) {
    TextEditingController controller;
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      // barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text(
            'Type record name',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
          ),
          content: TextField(
              controller: controller,
              onChanged: (value) {
                name = value;
              }),
          actions: [
            MaterialButton(
              elevation: 5.0,
              child: Text('Save'),
              onPressed: () {
                listCount.add(_item);
                print(_item);
                records[name] = _item;
                print(records);
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
            MaterialButton(
              elevation: 5.0,
              child: Text('Cancel'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

The variable _item is taking it's value from another site, see this:

```
StreamBuilder<int>(
                          stream: _stopWatchTimer2.rawTime,
                          initialData: 0,
                          builder: (context, snap) {
                            final value = snap.data;
                            final displayTime = StopWatchTimer.getDisplayTime(
                                value,
                                hours: _isHours2);
                            _item = displayTime;
                            return Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                              child: Text(displayTime,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 30.0, color: Colors.white)),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
```

And here where I create the ListView.builder:

```
ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: records.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return MyCard(
                  colour: Colors.cyanAccent,
                  maker: Container(
                    width: 250.0,
                    height: 75.0,
                    child: Text(
                      '${records[index]}',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
```

The image in the link is a screen shot from my app.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDCFH.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the _item variable which is initially null. You are not assigning any value to it. Please check your code. You are assigning a null value to your records because _item has not been given any value.

```
onChanged: (value){
  _item = value;
}
```

Comment: Actually I give values, and I print them in the console but when tried to show it in the app card, it falis and show Null !!

Comment: Can you post the complete code showing record list and where you assign value to the variable _item. In addition, can you print the last value of list count to be sure it doesn't return null also

Comment: I have edited my post, and in the code I show where the variable _item get it's value.
if it's nessessary I can post the whole code?
it's about 278 line in the same page

Answer (score 0):

you are not giving any value to the _item variable, I'm assuming you wanted to assign the value in the onChanged event like this:

```
onChanged: (value) {
                _item = value;
              }
```

or maybe you wanted to add the name to the list instead?

Comment: Actually I give values, and I print them in the console but when tried to show it in the app card, it falis and show Null !!

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, you have stored the item values into the records based on name variable in Save button onPressed event. But you are getting the record through the ListView index values. So, there is no record found in the records collection based on that index. So it returns null value.

Provide the index to store the item in the Save button instead of name. Or check the record based on name inside the ListView builder instead of index.